# SVG background images with Flying Saucer

Tags: java, svg, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I'm using FlyingSaucer's ITextRenderer to create PDFs from XML and CSS. I would like to specify a CSS background-image referencing an SVG image. I have things working fine with a PNG but not an SVG image.

I attempted to make a ChainedReplacedElementFactory to replace SVG nodes but that doesn't work since these SVG files are not referenced from the document but rather the CSS via url().

Is there any way to teach FlyingSaucer how to handle SVG files referenced from CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to figure this out. The trick is to customize the user agent.

```
class CustomUserAgent extends ITextUserAgent 
{
  private final ITextOutputDevice mDevice;

  public CustomUserAgent(ITextOutputDevice dev)
  {
    super(dev);
    mDevice = dev;
  }

  private static final SAXSVGDocumentFactory mFactory = 
    new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(null);

  private ImageResource getSVGImage(String uri)
    throws IOException, BadElementException
  {
    InputStream is = null;

    try
    {
      is = resolveAndOpenStream(uri);
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
      Document doc = mFactory.createSVGDocument(null, isr);
      UserAgent ua = new UserAgentAdapter();
      DocumentLoader loader = new DocumentLoader(ua);
      BridgeContext ctx = new BridgeContext(ua, loader);
      ctx.setDynamicState(BridgeContext.DYNAMIC);
      GVTBuilder builder = new GVTBuilder();
      String not_numbers = "[^0-9.,]";
      float width = 
        Float.parseFloat(doc.getDocumentElement().
                         getAttribute("width").replaceAll(not_numbers, ""));
      float height =
        Float.parseFloat(doc.getDocumentElement().
                         getAttribute("height").replaceAll(not_numbers, ""));
      PdfWriter writer = mDevice.getWriter();
      PdfTemplate templ = PdfTemplate.createTemplate(writer, width, height);
      Graphics2D g2d = templ.createGraphics(width, height);
      GraphicsNode gfx = builder.build(ctx, doc);
      gfx.paint(g2d);
      g2d.dispose();
      Image img = new ImgTemplate(templ);
      img.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);

      SharedContext shctx = getSharedContext();
      float dpi = shctx.getDotsPerPixel();
      if (dpi != 1.0f)
        img.scaleAbsolute(img.getPlainWidth()  * dpi,
                          img.getPlainHeight() * dpi);

      return new ImageResource(uri, new ITextFSImage(img));
    }
    finally
    {
      if (is != null)
        is.close();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public ImageResource getImageResource(String uri)
  {
    if (uri.endsWith(".svg"))
    {
      try
      { return (getSVGImage(uri)); }
      catch(IOException io)
      { throw new RuntimeException(io); }
      catch(BadElementException be)
      { throw new RuntimeException(be); }
    }
    else
      return (super.getImageResource(uri));
  }   
}
```

Then to use it you just apply it to the renderer:

```
CustomUserAgent callback =
  new CustomUserAgent(renderer.getOutputDevice());
callback.setSharedContext(renderer.getSharedContext());
renderer.getSharedContext().setUserAgentCallback(callback);
```

Comment: We used this code in our project and found that it works. But when used by multiple threads mFactory.createSVGDocument(null, isr) start throwing random NullPointerExceptions. The root cause for this is that mFactory is declared as static. So to solve this problem we just removed the static declaration.